# Why when hovering my mouse over an object in unity is it calling it the wrong object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, events

I decided to try create a simple cookie clicker game as my first solo project with no tuts or courses, I managed to get to a point where I can click on my "Cookie" and it adds 1 to the cookieCounter however unity seems to think everything is my cookie...

Not sure if it's my code or something in unity set up wrong but I am sure someone here could point me in the right direction.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

public class cookieCounter : MonoBehaviour
{

    public TextMeshProUGUI countText;
    public GameObject Cookie;
    private int count = 0;
    private Rigidbody rb;
    private string Object;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        count = 0;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) // On left click
        {
            Debug.Log(gameObject.name); //Returns the Object of which was clicked on
            OnMouseOver();
            countText.text = count.ToString("Cookies: 0"); // Updates the cookie counter on screen
            Debug.Log(count); // Returns Final Count
        }

        

    }
    private void OnMouseOver() // Looks at mouse and what it is hovering
    {

        Object = (gameObject.name); // Detects what the mouse is hovering over

        if (Object == "Cookie") // Makes sure the object mouse is hovering is the "Cookie"
        {
            count++; // Adds 1 to the cookie counter.
        }
    }

}
```

Please ignore the inefficient code I haven't done this before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You check if the mouse is clicked and current object is `"Cookie"`, but you don't check where the click happened. If `Cookie` object shares same `Update`/`OnMouseOver` methods as in question code, it will increase `count` no matter where the click was.

You can fix it by taking mouse position into consider. If Cookie is UI, you can let `Button` class handle everything related to detecting mouse click(the easy way).

If Cookie is 2D `SpriteRenderer` object(or 3D) then you can use `EventSystem`(possibly already included in your project) and implement `IPointerClickHandler` in Cookie class. You can find detailed solution in internet, like https://forum.unity.com/threads/solved-detecting-mouse-click-on-an-object-in-2d-game.478514/ .

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the function OnMouseDown() instead (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)).
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html

The difference is OnMouseDown will be called when you click on the object (the object must have a collider). Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) will be called when you click everywhere on the screen.